# PostgreSQL: Is it possible to get a different function result type (i.e. TABLE) in stored function based on input?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, set-returning-functions

The question is as follow, I wanted to get some flexibility in my example function, so based on input arguments to function I wanted to return different table as an output result.

So is it possible to get something like this in function definition:

```
RETURNS TABLE (
    customer_id INTEGER,
    first_name VARCHAR(45),
    last_name VARCHAR(45),
    country VARCHAR(50)
)

OR

RETURNS TABLE (
    message VARCHAR
)
```

My broken example function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customer_by_country(
    country_name VARCHAR, 
    id_flag BOOLEAN
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    customer_id INTEGER,
    first_name VARCHAR(45),
    last_name VARCHAR(45),
    country VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
$$
<<function_body>>
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF id_flag THEN
      RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT 
          cstmr.customer_id,
          cstmr.first_name,
          cstmr.last_name,
          cntr.country
        FROM 
          customer AS cstmr
        JOIN address ON cstmr.address_id = address.address_id
        JOIN city ON address.city_id = city.city_id
        JOIN country AS cntr ON city.country_id = cntr.country_id
        WHERE 
        cntr.country = country_name;
    ELSE
      RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT 'flag was not provided';
    END IF;
END function_body;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT get_customer_by_country('Belgium', false);
```

I searched for a questions like `ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type`, but haven't found anything that matched my case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*so based on input arguments to function I wanted to return different table as an output result*" - no that's not possible.

Comment: Any reference in docs?

Comment: No the documents do not state that outright,  but the  documentation does state the RETURNS must be declared as part of the CREATE Function declaration see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html  section rettype

Answer (score 3):

First off, you should take a look at Erwin Brandstetter's answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23957098/835781

If the return type you want is mimicked by the structure of an existing table, you could use that existing table's regclass to define the type of the results.  That method seems to be a bit overkill for your use case, if I'm understanding it correctly.

My suggestion would be to just create two functions.  If you need to keep the same name, I would suggest you overload the function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customer_by_country(
    country_name VARCHAR
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    customer_id INTEGER,
    first_name VARCHAR(45),
    last_name VARCHAR(45),
    country VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
$$ ... $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customer_by_country(
    country_name VARCHAR, 
    id_flag BOOLEAN
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    message VARCHAR
)
AS
$$ ... $$ ;
```

This results in you still having to create two function definitions.  If you're going to create two separate functions, you should probably just use different names for each.  If your application code is expecting the two different result sets depending on the flag provided, why not interpret that flag in your application code and use that to determine which function to call?

If you're dead-set on returning two different data structures depending on the value of a variable, you can't use the schema of an existing table to define the result type, and you're ok with the processing overhead, then you could create an array or json return type.  This gives your function the flexibility to build out the result in whatever format you choose, but requires additional processing and logic handling to interpret.  At the end of the day, it's usually just easier to create different functions for the different result types.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare it as RETURNS SETOF RECORD, so that the structure of the table is not defined at the time you create the function.

But it still must be known at the time you **call** the function.  If you want to figure out the return type after the call comes back, this still won't do what you want.

```
SELECT * from get_customer_by_country('Belgium', false) f(x text);
SELECT * from get_customer_by_country('Belgium', true) f(customer_id INTEGER, first_name VARCHAR(45), last_name VARCHAR(45), country VARCHAR(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already had some great answers, with links to more great answers. And, yeah, you're struggling with the requirement for defined inputs and outputs...it feels weird coming from other contexts. The best solutions I've seen are to 1) embrace it...you get a lot of power and avoid a lot of errors by accepting the declarative nature of SQL and 2) use JSON for cases where you genuinely need to generate an unpredictable output.

I thought I'd add a note about declaring types, a very cool Postgres feature people mentioned above (or in the lined answers.) As you may or may not have found out already, there are a *lot* of ways to define a custom type in Postgres, including at least the following:

`CREATE TYPE` manually creates a type with the definition you supply. The syntax looks like a C `struct`, more-or-less. Or like an unadorned table/view declaration.

`CREATE TABLE` automatically creates a type with the same name.

`CREATE VIEW` automatically creates a type with the same name.

`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` automatically creates a type with the same name.

These end up creating entries in the `pg_class` catalog table. That's also why you can get name clashes amongst these things, at least if they're in the same schema.

Anyway, if you do want to declare a custom return type that you use in a few places, `CREATE TYPE` is very simple to use. And, if you go that way, you might also find `CREATE CAST` interesting. For what it's worth, it's likely more useful to use `CREATE VIEW` as then you get a view, and automatically have a custom type to work with.

Comment: How does it even related to my question? Can you write more explicit or direct answer or is it just a bunch of text?

Comment: The answer related to part of your problem, expanding on answers you got or were referred to. When you declare `RETURNS TABLE`, that's in embedded/implicit type. Sometimes, it's easier to create a full type that's then visible and reusable. So, you would `RETURN my_type`, where `my_type` is a defined, compound type. If that's not of interest to you, fine. If it is of interest to you, the answer lists several ways to define a type. Free tip: You seem to be new to StackOverflow, there's an emphasis on being polite. You'll get more help that way too.